# Proxy won't work in chrome and only partly in firefox

Tags: c#

I've written a proxy in c#. It works by getting the http request from the browser sending the request to the site and sending back the site's response to the client. It works in firefox but some of the pages are cut like if it did not send all the response and in chrome it gives blank pages and for google.co.uk in chrome the browser gives "no data received". Can you see a mistake in my code which might be causing all this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LexProxy
{
    class ProxyServer
    {
        private TcpListener tcpListener;

        public ProxyServer()
        {
            this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3000);
            this.tcpListener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");
                TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
                {
                    Serve(client);
                });
                thread.Start();
            }
        }

        private void Serve(TcpClient client)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] request = GetBytesFromStream(stream, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            if (request != null)
            {
                string requestString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(request);
                string[] requestParts = requestString.Split(' ');
                if (requestParts.Length >= 2)
                {
                    string method = requestParts[0];
                    if (!requestParts[1].Contains("http://") && !requestParts[1].Contains("https://"))
                        requestParts[1] = "http://" + requestParts[1];

                    Uri uri = new Uri(requestParts[1], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                    string host = StringUtils.ReplaceFirst(uri.Host, "www.", "");
                    int port = uri.Port;
                    byte[] response = getResponse(host, port, request);
                    if (response != null)
                        stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private byte[] getResponse(string host, int port, byte[] request)
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(host, port);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            stream.Write(request, 0, request.Length);
            byte[] response = GetBytesFromStream(stream, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            return response;
        }

        private byte[] GetBytesFromStream(NetworkStream stream, int bufferSize)
        {
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[bufferSize];
            int i;
            while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                return bytes;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One minor error is that you're using `UTF8` to read first line of request.  HTTP request line and headers are `ASCII` (and body *may* be `UTF8`, but doesn't have to be, and may not even be a string at all).  The reason it works is b/c for english charset, UTF8 and ASCII happen to be encoded using the same bytes.  But that's the minor issue.

Most likely primary issue is hiding in your `GetBytesFromStream`.  You only call `.Read` once, but that doesn't guarantee that the whole message is returned.  It may return as little as just 1 byte... so you need to continue getting more data.  How do you know how much more? It's dictated by HTTP protocol which you'd need to properly parse and examine.  (At a minimum you're reading until you reach `\r\n\r\n` byte sequence indicating the end of request headers.

However, this is not enough as there may be a request body, length of which will be specified via an HTTP header, `Content-Length:` (IIRC), or possibly using [chunked encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). I don't see any code beyond URI examination, so most likely you do not handle HTTP messaging protocol itself, and so it is unlikely to work properly (unless you somehow manage to force browser to use `HTTP/0.9` or `HTTP/1.0` since those do not reuse connection and send one message per connection, at which point you could just blindly read everything the socket has to give you until browser signals the end of stream by closing its write endpoint of the connection).

But your main problem is that `GetBytesFromStream` as written won't give you "all" bytes.