# Get all bytes from stream

Tags: c#, sockets, http, tcp

I'm writing a proxy in c# and I wrote this method to get bytes from the stream but after looking at answer in this thread : [Proxy won't work in chrome and only partly in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501798/proxy-wont-work-in-chrome-and-only-partly-in-firefox/23502208?noredirect=1#23502208) I realize that I do not get all the bytes. How can I solve this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LexProxy
{
    class ProxyServer
    {
        private TcpListener tcpListener;

        public ProxyServer()
        {
            this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3000);
            this.tcpListener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");
                TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
                {
                    Serve(client);
                });
                thread.Start();
            }
        }

        private void Serve(TcpClient client)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] request = GetBytesFromStream(stream, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            if (request != null)
            {
                string requestString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(request);
                string[] requestParts = requestString.Split(' ');
                if (requestParts.Length >= 2)
                {
                    string method = requestParts[0];
                    if (!requestParts[1].Contains("http://") && !requestParts[1].Contains("https://"))
                        requestParts[1] = "http://" + requestParts[1];

                    Uri uri = new Uri(requestParts[1], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                    string host = StringUtils.ReplaceFirst(uri.Host, "www.", "");
                    int port = uri.Port;
                    byte[] response = getResponse(host, port, request);
                    if (response != null)
                        stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private byte[] getResponse(string host, int port, byte[] request)
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(host, port);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            stream.Write(request, 0, request.Length);
            byte[] response = GetBytesFromStream(stream, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            return response;
        }

        private byte[] GetBytesFromStream(NetworkStream stream, int bufferSize)
        {
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[bufferSize];
            int i;
            while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                return bytes;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this sample Proxy Server instead:

http://times.imkrisna.com/2011/08/simple-http-proxy-server-c-source-code/

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this wrong. Instead of trying to gather the entire response before sending it downstream, you should just be copying bytes as they arrive. No need to add latency.

But note that the code you have written in getAllBytesFromStream() is nonsense. You have a while loop with an unconditional return statement in it. How is that ever going to execute more than once?